# Computer joining a domain doesnt join a specific OU

Tags: active-directory

im working at a company that has a domain name (we'll call it Super) divided into the following OU's
X, Y, A, B and Z.
im an administrator of the Y domain only, so i cant access anything else beyond the Y ou.
i have recently encountered a problem where's i use my administrator user to let a new computer into our OU using active directory, but whenever i use my credentials on the new added machine it is being automatically added to the Super domain, but not the Y OU that i administer, so i cant touch it once its inside the domain. i also dont have any way to move it between OU's aside from calling my superiors and ask them to move it for me, but i dont want to do that for every new pc deployed into my OU network. how can i solve this problem and make new computers show up immediately in my OU?

Answer (score 0):

You can either pre-stage the computer object in the required OU, or use the -OUPath parameter of the Add-Computer cmdlet.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-computer?view=powershell-5.1